# Laravel Facebook Login : Error app_id is required

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1, I want to add facebook social login to my page, but it is returning error

```
The parameter app_id is required
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'UserController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback', 'UserController@callback');
```

**UserController**

```
public function redirect(){
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}
```

**Composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
     "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
}
```

**Config/Services.php**

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '222221956976734',
    'client_secret' => 'a5acf8e8e01745d47rer829a0094vfvf',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost/myproject/public/callback',
],
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/redirect') }}" style="background-color : rgb(59,89,152)" class="btn blue_btn_big">Login via Facebook</a>
```

What I have missed here..Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Everything look correct. Just wondering have you install mbstring?

Comment: how to check mbstring in laravel ?? Its very strange situation for me, everything I followed properly but not working...... :(

Comment: mbstring is kind of php extension. According to official doc file said min PHP5.4, mbstring and composer. I just suspect.

Comment: Yes I'm sure mbstring is there because in the same application I'm already using login via gmail.

Comment: If your using ubuntu, use sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring or centos yum install php5.6-mbstring

Comment: I'm using windows 7..

Comment: Create php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and load in the browser. Use search for `mbstring`.

Comment: have you got any solution for this @Aamir

Comment: Yes I resolved it.

Comment: @Aamir how did you resolve this?

Comment: @whoacowboy Its been a year now, I think there was some issue with incorrect client id and client secret.

Comment: @Aamir thanks for the response. It turns out one of the load balanced servers wasn't configured properly.