# error parameter app_id is required

Tags: laravel, php-5.5

I installed Laravel5.5  Socialite 3.3, but can't make it work. It shows the error on the facebook page

> parameter app_id is required.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

Please check below code in `config/service.php`:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '222221956976734',
    'client_secret' => 'a5acf8e8e01745d47rer829a0094vfvf',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost/myproject/public/callback',
],
```

Or more details please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542686/laravel-facebook-login-error-app-id-is-required)

Comment: hi,thanks for your rply..But ,i did everything above mentioned (include link) details.still not working. Thank you again :)

Comment: @arulkumar Please give me some code like config/service.php and your controller code

Comment: solution 'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '834376266725298',
        'client_secret' => 'ff16fbee7f21424daa2f08e4a1981590',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost/blog/public/callback',
    ]

Comment: Please once you clear the cache because client_id and all stored in config file so please clear the cache like:

php artisan config:cache, 
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @addwebSolutionYeah thanks.it working fine .but now i get the error like ** Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. **

Comment: @arulkumar: Please see this link(https://screenshots.firefox.com/j7oyK8jtz3IOpIxt/addwebsolutionteam.slack.com) and put your domain url here Note: here local url  not work

Comment: @addwebsloution Now it workking fine.thanks a lot :)